# Change Telerik Metro theme Font Size at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik, caliburn.micro

According to Telerik's documentation you can change the font-size of the themes included, in this case I've tried to change the metro font-size from + - buttons on my application, but its not working.

Im using `Caliburn MVVM`, first I've tried this code on a method in my `viewmodel`

```
 Windows8Palette.Palette.FontSize += 1
 Windows8Palette.Palette.FontSizeL += 1
 Windows8Palette.Palette.FontSizeXL += 1
```

The fontsize does change when the view is reloaded (TryClose and activated again), but I want to change it on the spot, Ive tried:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.InvalidateVisual()
```

I've also tried executing the code in code behind, but it doesn't work, is there something that allow me to do it?

Comment: I think you will need a reload of the visual elements - whether that call to `MainWindow.InvalidateVisual()` flows down to child elements I don't know - might be that it doesn't affect child elements across control boundaries (since if CM you will usually be using usercontrols for views)

Comment: How can I do that, I've tried InvalidateVisual even on a button.